# How can I hidden the user-menu-dropwn element in welcome page?

Tags: html, apache-superset

[image] this element, I try to modify templates/appbuilder/navbar_right.html [image]
and does not work in welcome page but in other page it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question. the code is this `/superset/superset-fronted/src/components/Menu/UserMenu.jsx`,add `style={{display: 'none'}}` in this file